# Website URL rework / reformat to user-friendly

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, asp-classic

I need some advice on where and how I should start this project. The current site is running classic ASP but uses .php extensions in the file system (don't ask - previous freelance).

Current URL structure has sub folders that contains display pages that renders the page

```
team/team_detail.php?teamID=3&Source=Title&Title=Partner
```

Only the `teamID` part actually does anything and query the data in a team table.

I was thinking of using the `IIS url rule` and add `user friendly rule` for each matching URL patterns. I was planning to change all website code to use new structure:

url `team/team_detail/3/bob-titans`

Old url formant that will still work `team/team_detail.php?teamID=3&name=bob-titans`

Would this complete site wide URL change be the most effective way to do this or would there be another more effective method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main objective is to change the URL structure of the site (and clean up stuff like the unused "Source" and "Title" parameters while you're at it), then the approach is sound:

- Modify the site code to use the new URL strategy (for example, with ASP.NET Routing).
- Use the IIS  URL Rewrite Module to create rules to properly redirect or rewrite the old-style requests to the new format. If this is a public site, and you are concerned about SEO, you should consider making these redirects use the 301 response type to tell search engines the resources under the old URLs have moved permanently to the new URLs.

It's a nice approach because you can focus on updating your code for the new structure, and let IIS take care of any users still referencing the old URL formats.